# how to pass Array values from js to JSP file using action

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

**js file:**

> why does the size of dropdown1 is coming as 1?

```
function savethechanges(){
for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    dropdown1[i]=document.getElementById("sel"+i).value;
    kot[i]=document.getElementById("kot"+i).value;
    item[i]=document.getElementById("itemcode"+i).value;
    if(dropdown1[i] == 0){
        document.detailsview.action="BillCB.jsp?method=" + "11" + "&itemcode=" +item[i]+ "&kot=" +kot[i]+ "&itemStatus1=" +dropdown1[i]+ "&billno=" +billno;
    }
    else if(dropdown1[i] == 1){
        document.detailsview.action="BillCB.jsp?method="+"9"+"&itemcode="+item[i]+"&kot="+kot[i]+"&itemStatus1="+dropdown1[i]+ "&billno="+billno;
    }
    else{
        document.detailsview.action= "BillCB.jsp?method="+"10"+"&itemcode="+item[i]+"&kot="+kot[i]+"&itemStatus1="+dropdown1[i]+ "&billno="+billno;
    }
}
}
```

**JSP file:**

> while retrieving here the dropdown1 length is 1.but for kot and item length is 18
>   please provide your solution!

```
 case 11:
 gotMethod = true;
 billdetails_be.billno = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("billno"));
 String[] kotCB2=request.getParameterValues("kot");
 String[] itemCB2=request.getParameterValues("itemcode");
 String[] statCB2=request.getParameterValues("itemStatus1");
 int[] kotarr2=new int[kotCB2.length];
 int[] itemarr2=new int[itemCB2.length];
 int[] statarr2=new int[statCB2.length];
 System.out.println("IN AVAILABLE:length of array is:"+statCB2.length);
 System.out.println("IN AVAILABLE:length of array is:"+kotCB2.length);
 for(int i=1;i<itemarr2.length;i++)
 {   
     kotarr2[i]=Integer.parseInt(kotCB2[i]);
 }
 for(int i=1;i<itemarr2.length;i++)
 {  
     itemarr2[i]=Integer.parseInt(itemCB2[i]);
 }
 for(int i=1;i<itemarr2.length;i++)
 { 
     statarr2[i]=Integer.parseInt(statCB2[i]);  
 }
 for(int i=1;i<itemarr2.length;i++)
 {
     int kotint2=kotarr2[i];
     int itemint2=itemarr2[i];
     int statint2=statarr2[i];
     System.out.println( i+"the value of kot in available"+ kotint2);
     int availablebill = websrv.availablebill(billdetails_be.billno, kotint2,   itemint2,statint2); 
  }
```

**design page(jsp)**

```
<%
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
%>
<TR>
<TD>  <input id="itemcode<%=i%>" type="hidden" name="itemcode" value=" <%=billdetails_be.get(i).itemcode%>"></TD>
<TD><%=billdetails_be.get(i).itemdescription%></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="quantity<%=i%>" type="text" name="quantity"  style="width:  30px;" readOnly="readonly" value="<%=billdetails_be.get(i).quantity%>" >
<input type="submit"  id="inc<%=i%>" onclick= "doIt1(1,<%=i%>);"  value="+" style="width:20px; height:20px; border-radius:10px; padding:0 0; " /> 
<input type="submit"  id="dec<%=i%>" onclick="doIt1(-1,<%=i%>);"   value="-" style="width:20px; height:20px; border-radius:10px; padding:0 0; "/>
</TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=billdetails_be.get(i).price%></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=billdetails_be.get(i).itemstatusdescription%></TD>
<td>
<select name="statusi" id="sel<%=i%>">
<option value="0">Available</option>
<option value="1">Unavailable</option>
<option value="2">Delete</option>
</select> 
</td>               
<td> <input id ="kot<%=i%>" type="text" style="border: 0px solid #000000;" name="kot"   style="cursor: text" readonly="readonly" value="<%=billdetails_be.get(i).kotno%>"></td>         
<TD> <input id="myquantity<%=i%>" type="hidden" name="quantity1" value="     <%=billdetails_be.get(i).quantity%>"></TD>
</TR> 
<%
} 
%>
<td><input style="width: 150px; " class="btn btn-green btn-large" type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="save"  class="button" onclick="savetheChanges(<%=count%>);">    </td>
```

**PROBLEM**

> 1.this is in js file ,from which i am passing the value to BillCB.jsp

```
 document.detailsview.action="BillCB.jsp?method=" + "11" + "&itemcode=" +itemcode1[i]+ "&kot=" +kot1[i]+ "&itemStatus1=" +selection[i]+ "&billno=" +billno;
```

> 2.this is in BillCB.jsp file (method :11)

```
 String[] statCB2=request.getParameterValues("itemStatus1");
 int[] statarr2=new int[statCB2.length];
 System.out.println("IN AVAILABLE:length of STATUS array is:"+statCB2.length);
```

> In AVAILABLE:length of STATUS array is:1-this is the problem.

Comment: If it's possible then don't write too much java code in `JSP`, instead pass processed output only and present on `JSP`, because if `page crash` then people can see your code easily.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through your code but you might try this solution

Use JSON.stringify method to stringify the array data then send the stringified data to server using below line.

data=JSON.stringify("yourArrayName")

then send "data" as a parameter to JSP

On server side convert it back to array data.

Comment: Yeah..I agree with you.but the problem is I'm getting the other values perfectly.(kot1,itemcode1).pls have a look at.

Comment: I think you are using "get" method to send data from JS to JSP. "get" method supports upto 256 characters so change the method from "get" to "post"

Comment: I have given as post only!

Comment: You're sending a parameter named as method. It might be causing problems for you. If its possible can you change the name of the parameter method and try once?

Comment: It would be great if you could share you plain HTML file in which you are sending data to server?

Comment: I don't have method in that name and I am just passing the values to webservice function.but in jsp file itself i cann't get the value properly.

Comment: I think I cant understand ur problem correctly.
You are sending a set of values from JS to JSP. and JS is itself in JSP right? can you provide the program flow correctly with filenames and contents

Comment: Billdetails>BillCB.jsp>Mywebserve.java.I'm passing the values of dropdown,itemcode,kot to BillCb.jsp.now see once again ,hope you'll get it.